# Vert.x: best way to log to file

Tags: java, performance, vert.x

What is the fastest async way to log to file in Vert.x?

The aim is to write logs from loggers from different classes (i.e. Class1, Class2 etc) to 1 file (something like 'console.log')

Comment: You should at least specify which version of `Vert.x` you are using? what have you done so far? What type of application are you developping?

Answer (score 4):

*Vert.x* uses the JDK bundled JUL logging framework to avoid shipping additional dependencies. However it allows to append a custom logger implementation.

Assuming that you want to stick to the default logging facility, customizing the log handler would then be as easy as droping a logging file and referencing it through the `java.util.logging.config.file` system property:

- For example you can drop the logging configuration file under a *config* directory under the root path of your (fat) jar which may look as follows:

  ```
  handlers = java.util.logging.MyFileHandler
  config   =
  #...
  ```
- You should then refrence that file in a system property as follows when starting your *Vert.x* application:

  ```
  -Djava.util.logging.config.file=config/logging.properties
  ```
- You can then access the `Logger` object in your classes as follows:

  ```
  Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("some.package.MyClass");
  ```
- Use that logger to log messages that will be handled by the configured handler(s):

  ```
  logger.info("some informative message");
  ```

Note the use of a custom log handler in the properties file to emphasis the possibily of appending your own handler (which may extend the default [`FileHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/FileHandler.html)).

Check the *Vert.x* documentation for more informations on how to use explore [the logging feature](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_logging).

Answer (score 2):

Most of loggers are async from the beginning , i.e. they are not write information immediately. Logs are stored into buffer, which is flushed by timeout  or when it is full. So slf4j + log4 is good enough for most cases.